# Set Property of UserControl in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, class, binding, datagrid

I'm working on a program for playing audio files and have ran into some issues with one of my DataGrids. Basically it's meant to allow the user change settings for it *(Listen, repeat and volumes for example)*.

For this I have made my own UserControl, which is being dynamically added via DataTemplates in XAML. So first of all here's some context;

**SoundFile.cs** *(public class)*
Class that has file-related properties such as Name, Path, Category and Volumes.

**SoundLibrary.cs** *(public static)*
This is a static class which keeps track of all SoundFiles inside an ObservableCollection, this is the collection used to populate my DataGrids.

**SoundControl.cs** *(UserControl)*
This is my UserControl which consists of a few buttons, it has a property for *SoundFile* which is what I'm confused as to how to set and/or properly access.

This is how my DataGrid is defined;

```xml
<DataGrid
    x:Name="MyDataGrid"
    Margin="0,0,0,36"
    AlternationCount="2"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    IsReadOnly="True"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Listen Volume">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Slider
                        Margin="5"
                        Maximum="100"
                        Minimum="0"
                        Value="{Binding DataContext.ListenVolume, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Settings">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:SoundControl x:Name="SoundController" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Progress">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ProgressBar
                        Maximum="100"
                        Minimum="0"
                        Visibility="Visible"
                        Value="50" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And here's how I bind it in code behind;

```cs
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = SoundLibrary.Library;

for (int i = 0; i < MyDataGrid.Items.Count; i++)
{
    SoundFile sf = (SoundFile)MyDataGrid.Items.GetItemAt(i);
    Debug.WriteLine(sf.FilePath);
}
```

Doing that I can access the SoundFile as expected, however I'm not sure how to access the SoundFile through the **SoundControl**.

The SoundControl class is very simple;

```cs
public partial class SoundControl : UserControl
{
    public SoundFile Sound { get; set; } = new SoundFile();

    public SoundControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ListenButton.IsToggled = Sound.Listen;
        RepeatButton.IsToggled = Sound.Repeat;
    }

    private void GridButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender == ListenButton)
        {
            Sound.Listen = ListenButton.IsToggled;
            MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
            mainWindow.UnsavedChanges = true;
        }

        if (sender == RepeatButton)
        {
            Sound.Repeat = RepeatButton.IsToggled;
            MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Window.GetWindow(this);
            mainWindow.UnsavedChanges = true;
        }

        if (sender == FolderButton)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Sound.FilePath);
            //Sound.OpenDirectory();
        }
    }
}
```

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated, still relatively new to data binding and using DataGrids... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Sound` property of the SoundControl should be a bindable property, i.e. dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SoundProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Sound), typeof(SoundFile), typeof(SoundControl));

public SoundFile Sound
{
    get { return (SoundFile)GetValue(SoundProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SoundProperty, value); }
}
```

You would bind it to the current SoundFile item of the DataGrid row like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Settings">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:SoundControl Sound="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Thanks! I ran into this while researching this issue before I posted but wasn't able to get it to work. Wasn't setting up the DependencyProperty properly so I got some more reading to do!

1 last thing, what'd be a good way to detect when the DependencyProperty is set? So I can update the states of the buttons etc. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged?

Thanks again!

Comment: Ah never mind that, the loaded event for the UserControl worked just fine. The buttons now work as intended!

Now I just gotta work out the bindings for the volume sliders, since they're not part of the UserControl... The DataGridTextColumn can retrieve the name just fine - not sure why the TemplateColumns fail to get the volume properties. Context related?